# Forgot Name Game?

Tags: game-center

i want to know a old game that i played when I was young, probably when i was 7/8/9 (?) years old. I just know that in the game we are like swat team, me and two more guys (bots). I just played the trail version and the mission was in a prison with terrorists (i think they was terrorists, they have camo clothes). I know that in the start of this trail version we enter a door and we can see the first terrorist with a table in front of him. i think after was a laundry room. when we enter the cells room i think inside two of them was more terrorists. i´m curious to know the name of this game, I can´t remember more beacuse i was young. please i´m very curious, i need to know this game name!!!

Comment: can you translate "when i was 7/8/9" into a year for us? Do you remember which console you played the game on?

Comment: Try Ask Reddit for non-programming related questions! https://www.reddit.com/r/askreddit